# Xamarin.Forms "styles.xml" is not affecting anything

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have this listview in my xamarin.forms app:

```
            MenuItems = new List<ListViewDetail>(new[]
            {
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 0, Title = "Mein Profil" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 1, Title = "Meine Anzeigen" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 2, Title = "Merkliste" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 3, Title = "Website" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 4, Title = "Kontakt" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 5, Title = "Hilfe" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 6, Title = "Einstellungen" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 7, Title = "Missbrauch melden" },
                new ListViewDetail { Id = 8, Title = "Log Out" },

            });
```

Unfortunately, the items selected background color is this nasty orange (on iOS it is grey, which is fine, but on Android it is orange).

A solution should be to just change the styles in the styles.xml:

```
  <color name="ListViewSelected">#96BCE3</color>
  <color name="ListViewHighlighted">#E39696</color>
```

But this is not affecting anything. 
Am I doing it wrong or do I need to set anything else in order to adress the styles?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two steps to implement this function .

1. Specify ViewCell as DataTemplate of ListView .

   ```
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                   <StackLayout>
                       <Label Text="{Binding . }"/>
                   </StackLayout>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   ```
2. Create custom renderer for ViewCell.

   ```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(MyRenderer))]
   namespace App2.Droid
   {
       public class MyRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
       {
           private Android.Views.View _cellCore;
           private Drawable _unselectedBackground;
           private bool _selected;
           protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
           {
               _cellCore = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
               _selected = false;
               _unselectedBackground = _cellCore.Background;
               return _cellCore;
           }
           protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
           {
               base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, args);
               if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
               {
                   _selected = !_selected;
                   if (_selected)
                   {
                       var extendedViewCell = sender as ViewCell;
                       _cellCore.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       _cellCore.SetBackground(_unselectedBackground);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: But that is not done via styles. I need it to be done with styles,xml